# Does the average Ivy League student have an IQ of 145?

Tags: intelligence, university

Psychology Professor Dr. Jordan B. Peterson gave a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ui52h2_gbos) in March 2017 where he said (in the first minute of the video):

> If you go back and look at the records at Harvard, for example, in the early 1960s, the typical IQ for a Harvard student was abouy 105 to 110 - not much above average. [...] Anyways the average Ivy League was bright, but not outstandingly so. Now, it is like an IQ of 145 - three standard deviations above the mean. The reason for that is that they are selected by the SAT.

But this [blog article](https://pumpkinperson.com/2015/04/13/do-harvard-students-have-an-average-iq-of-122/) references a 2003 study suggesting the Harvard average is about 122.

Is there any conclusive data on this?

Comment: Just to illuminate the claim, an IQ of 145 represents the [top 0.13% of the population](http://presskit.ditd.org/Davidson_Institute_Press_Kit/ditd_IQ_and_Educational_Needs.html).

Comment: Which is over 400,000 people in the US alone (assuming IQ is independent of location )

Comment: Harvard 15 years ago does not necessarily equate to all Ivy League schools 1 year ago.  Although somewhat suspicious; I wouldn't take the Harvard static as any type of evidence for that being incorrect (though I am interested in more information on this as well).

Comment: I'm battling to find any references that aren't blogs from dubious "researchers" for this claim. Either this is data from a minor source, or Peterson is just making up the claim based upon SATs and presumed associated IQ. Even then it is probably too high. Either way, Peterson isn't a reliable source of information. https://brainsize.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/the-iqs-of-academic-elites/

Comment: @ArcanistLupus and only about 5,700 people in the 18-year-old US population -- the Ivy league admits about two-and-a-half times that many students